# RiotJS mounting tag without subtags

Tags: riot.js

I am using tag-based routing with RiotJS. If the tag in the route contains an other tag, it is automatically mounted. Which is great in some cases. But there are cases when I need to pass some options to the tag being mounted, that can't be passed as tag property. I know that `this.tags` will contain them and I have the means to pass that parameter afterward. But I still am curious if there is a way to stop RiotJS automounting some subtags.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have a design error.
Remember that a tag can contain any classic JS code; you can simply write a logic that populates the tag in any time, way, shape or form. You can also hide it's content via the if condition until it is populated, while it is mounted. You can also hide it in the parent and prevent its mounting in the same manner if you so desire.

Comment: Please explain this sentence: _You can also hide it in the parent and prevent its mounting in the same manner if you so desire._. What I am doing now is exactly what you wrote: hiding the content when automounted. It works. But as you can pass runtime generated options when mounting (see: https://martinmuzatko.github.io/riot-cheatsheet/#templating-passing-values-on-mount) you can't do this if it is auto-mounted. This simplicity is what I am missing in this case.

Comment: @ZorgoZ - by auto-mounting you mean mount("*") as opposed to mount( tagname, options) ?

Comment: No, if you have a tag, that uses an other tag, if you mount the outer tag, the inner one is also mounted automatically. This way you dont have the opportunity to pass any options.

Comment: @ZorgoZ you can simply add whatever you want in the attribute.

Comment: Yes, but what if it is something calculated when the parent tag is mounted, or only afterwards at specific point in time? And I want to mount the sub-tag only when I have that domething?